# How to scale an image link to 100% of div using css?

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, href, scale

I am trying to scale an image to 100% width of the div it is contained within (it is a responsive layout with the div changing size depending on window size, hence the need to scale the images).

This is my css:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 520px) {
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

The images resize fine using this css, EXCEPT when they are links. Like this:

```
<div class="container">    
<a href="http://andreaalice.com/index.shtml"><img src="images/image.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Image links remain at their full size of 200px rather than scaling down to 100% of the div which is 100px.

Anyone know how I can get the linked images to scale?

Comment: Your code seems to work OK for me already. When the window width is less than 520px the image shrinks to 100x100px. Can you make a demo of the problem please?

Comment: Yes, the code you posted works fine, so something else in your styles is getting in the way.

Comment: @andyb You guys are right, this code seems to work so there must be something else getting in the way. I simplified it when I posted the question on here. I can't find what's causing the problem in my original files. I've uploaded a test version of the site here:
http://andreaalice.com/test/

You'll see it's the first image that doesn't scale. The problem is with .element div.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
.container a img {
    width: 100%;
 }
```

?

I made a quick example that seems to do what you need [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cU5e4/).

Comment: Yes @Robyflc this would be the correct answer in other circumstances, however I had other things in my code that prevented this from working, namely `position:aboslute` set on my container.

Comment: @user2419684 In the code you posted you have a position:relative set to the container. Did you change it to absolute after posting??

Comment: @Robyflc the code I posted was a simplified version of the issue I was having, rather than posting the code for my entire site. So the code I posted actually ended up working fine - and after uploading my entire site andyb discovered the problem was elsewhere in  `position: absolute` on my selected elements as seen in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recreate the problem in a [**simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2esxp/1/). Just shrink the results window to < 520px and the images *should* resize but the first one does not.

The problem seems to be the following rule

```
.element * {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Removing the `position:absolute;` fixes the problem. I *think* this is because the surrounding `<a>` on the first image has no `width`. Adding

```
.element a {
    width:100%;
}
```

fixes the problem when page width < 520px but that then breaks page with >= 520px! So I'd just recommend removing `position:absolute` unless you need that for any other reason. It doesn't seem to affect anything else on the page as far as I can see.

Lastly (and it's only minor) but all the `<img>` tags should really be [self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5). The page [nearly validates](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://andreaalice.com/test/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: You seem to have discovered the issue, however if I remove `position:absolute` I lose all the hover effects on the elements.

I think I've found another solution - not sure whether it's the best. I've taken the link off the images and instead created a separate link with a class to fill 100% of the div, and `z-index:1`. It also solves another problem I discovered: previously the text in my elements wasn't clickable because it was sitting in front of the images.
Updated code is here: http://andreaalice.com/test/

Comment: @Robyflc please don't try to get get attention from commenting on other answers. Please comment on the _question_ in future.

Comment: @user2419684 Yes, I missed the _hover_ part. I was only checking for fixing the resizing, sorry It looks like you've solved it another way now anyway, so well done! :-)

Comment: @andyb I thought this site was about helping other people and not about 'getting attention'.

Comment: @Robyflc There are still rules and best practice to follow. Your comment was wrongly placed for whatever reason which I was simply pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using  flex display. Try and paste this into your  inspect element tool

`element.style {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}`